# Protocol Checksum

Tags: c, protocols

i have onr protocol of the format

```
\003LLCCDDDD..DDXX
```

- LL: Total packet length not including the attention byte.
- CC: The command code.
- DD: Data bytes (in HEX ASCII).
- XX: The checksum of LLCCDDDD..DD (it does not include the attention byte nor the checksum itself). The checksum is a simple, 8bit summation of the ASCII characters in the command packet.

here is an example:

```
Command:    “\0030611C8”    (Length=6, command=0x11, checksum=0xC8)
```

i just want to know how checksum comes out to be 0xC8
thnx :)

Comment: protocol to send and receive commands from some device

Comment: what is the DATA bytes value in your cases. the length is not 0x06 now.

Comment: @wbao - it adds up to 6 for me.  \003 attention byte, followed by 6 bytes `0611C8`.

Comment: @Carl Norum `0611C8` is 3-bytes only.

Comment: @rjayavrp - No it's not.  It is 6 ASCII bytes.  That's a C string, of ASCII encoded bytes - not a typed-out representation of 3 native hex bytes.  It says right in the OP's post: "DD: Data bytes (in HEX ASCII)."

Comment: @Carl Norum... oh.. my fault :). Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As your description of the protocol states, the checksum is the sum of the bytes that aren't either the attention byte or the checksum.  You have a 7 byte transfer in total:

```
'\003', '0', '6', '1', '1', 'C', '8'
```

Of that, `\003` is the attention byte, so it's not included in the checksum.  Likewise, the last two characters *are* the checksum, and aren't included.  That leaves just 4 characters for your example:

```
'0', '6', '1', '1'
```

Translating from those characters into their hex representation (check an [ASCII table](http://asciitable.com)) to make them easier to add gives these results:

```
0x30, 0x36, 0x31, 0x31
```

Then you add those values together and get:

```
0xC8
```

Which is the answer you're looking for!

Comment: will you please elaborate more??

Comment: @james, what do you mean by elaborate more?  What part are you having a problem with?

Comment: i mean how '0' get converted to 0x30???

Comment: Did you look at the ASCII table I linked?  ASCII `'0'` is 0x30.  That's just all there is to it.

Comment: @james this answer is fine - you yourself are also supposed to make a little effort to understand things. SO won't feed you.

Answer (score 1):

It is my guess:

you checksum target code is 0611

let us do this:

ASCII(0) = 48, ASCII(6) = 54, ASCII(1) = 49;

get the sum of 4 ASCII is 200 = 0xC8